# Combining Unit Tests and Graphical output using QT

Tags: unit-testing, qt, boost

I want to use the BOOST testing framework and I also need a QApplication for visualization since some of my tests are very clearly visualized.
Hence I need to call QApplication exec() as last thing in my main and the exec is supposed to run as long as the window is not closed.

I tried the following code but it does not work as expected (no window) and needs manual test registration.

```
test_suite*
init_unit_test_suite( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MainWidget widget(0);

   test_suite* test= BOOST_TEST_SUITE( "Test case template example" );
   test->add(BOOST_TEST_CASE(&free_test_function2);
   //... many more tests

  widget.show();
  app.exec();
  return test;
}
```

How to use BOOST_TEST together with sth.like QApplication ?
Is it also possible with automatic test registration ?

Many thanks, Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider defining BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN and writing your own main function, which calls

```
::boost::unit_test::unit_test_main( &init_unit_test, argc, argv );
```

at the appropriate time. I suspect this needs to be done in a subthread, since Qt will most likely loop inside of `exec()` until all windows are closed.

Comment: True it loops. I hope there is a way without the introduction of threading because then every paint event from a test routine entails inter-thread communication. This would definitely be the end of the utility of BOOSTs testing framework for such scenarios.

Comment: @Martin: You might launch the Qt event handling routine for each test, or you might launch unit test main from within Qt.

Comment: Thanks again you pointed me in the right direction -> praise goes to you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it thanks to thitons comment and a lot of googling. Here is the code for the record (using boost 1_44 and the dynamic testing library):

```
//Testing the lib

//###################################################################################
//Setting up boost testing framework
#define BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE "Unit test for libcommon"

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>   //###################################################################################

#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>

using namespace boost::unit_test;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  (void) argc;
  (void) argv;

  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("utf8"));

  ::boost::unit_test::unit_test_main( &init_unit_test, argc, argv );

  return app.exec();
}
```

From this point on test files can add automatic tests and also create QWidgets and anything else inside those tests. QWidgets can e.g. be instantiated in fixtures but obviously they must not be destroyed at the fixtures destruction if the visual image is of interest (One obviously wouldn't see anything since the teardown of a fixture is called immediately after all tests of that suite)